# DB2 - How to get value for: Transation Per Minute parameter for DB?

Tags: db2, transaction

Hi is there some easy way to find out what is transaction per minute value for the database?
Should I use db2 get snapshot?
We are using DB2 9.7 ESE on Linux

Thank you in advance

Comment: The answer will depend on the DB2 version and platform.

Comment: Hi thank you for reply its DB2 ESE 9.7 on Linux. Does this helps you?

Comment: can you please assist me if this configuration is visible somewhere in shapshot file? how to find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are indeed interested in the transaction log sizing, not performance, you will get better information observing the actual log usage instead of the number of transactions.

```
$ db2 get snapshot for database on sample | grep "Log space"
Log space available to the database (Bytes)= 52893203
Log space used by the database (Bytes)     = 94797
```

Comment: Hi, thanks again. This statistics will show only for the time period when I turned MONITOR SWITCHES ON then do the GET SNAPSHOT and then MONITOR SWITCHES OFF? Am I right?

Comment: I did it: [ctginst1@tt-db-02 NODE0000]$ db2 get snapshot for database on maxdb71 | grep "Log space"
Log space available to the database (Bytes)= 466439444
Log space used by the database (Bytes)     = 1028844

Comment: What does Log space used by the database shows? Current usage of ACTIVE logs (which are not archived) or total usage since last restart of database?

Comment: It's the total of log space used by all currently active (not committed) transactions. I think you may want to start reading the manual, as everything you're asking is actually described there.

Comment: thank you for your info.
I foudn this also  select snapshot_timestamp,
db_conn_time,
commit_sql_stmts,
rollback_sql_stmts,
timestampdiff(4,snapshot_timestamp-db_conn_time) as minutes,db_conn_time,
(commit_sql_stmts+rollback_sql_stmts)/timestampdiff(4,snapshot_timestamp-db_conn_time) as transactions_per_minute 
from sysibmadm.snapdb

Answer (score 3):

There is no "per minute" metric available, you will need to query the monitor repeatedly and divide the delta of the metric you're after by the time interval since the previous query. The following two queries will return the total number of application units of work and the total number of completed units of work, respectively.

```
SELECT  
   TOTAL_APP_COMMITS + TOTAL_APP_ROLLBACKS
FROM SYSIBMADM.MON_DB_SUMMARY

SELECT  
   SUM(TOTAL_APP_COMMITS) +
   SUM(INT_COMMITS) +
   SUM(TOTAL_APP_ROLLBACKS) +
   SUM(INT_ROLLBACKS) 
FROM TABLE(MON_GET_WORKLOAD('',-2))
```

There are other monitor views that you may find useful: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0023485.html#r0023485__mon_23485

You can obtain the same information using the `GET SNAPSHOT` command, but the use of old-style snapshot monitor is not recommended. For example, you can try this:

```
db2 get snapshot for database on sample | grep -Ei "commit|rollback"
```

Comment: When I try to run your first command I am getting error that table does not exist. if I run your second command I am getting null value as result (is it because my DB is now in CIRCULAR mode) this seems that does not help me

Comment: Check out the note at http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0056513.html: If your database was created in Version 9.7 before Fix Pack 1, to run this routine you must have already run the db2updv97 command.

Comment: These are db info: fix pakc 0:[ctginst1@tt-db-02 NODE0000]$ db2level
DB21085I  Instance "ctginst1" uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL09070" 
with level identifier "08010107".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v9.7.0.0", "s090521", "LINUXAMD6497", and Fix 
Pack "0".

Comment: OK, so you'll need to upgrade to a more recent fix pack. Until then you can still use the `GET SNAPSHOT` command to obtain the same metrics, but the use of traditional snapshots is not recommended.

Comment: I tried with ctginst1 user to do in command editor : select * from mon_db_summary notginh is returned? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you please advise me what metrics should I watch in GET SNAPSHOT to have these metrics?

Comment: Sorry for lots of these questions but you know everyone tell me that to set properly LOGPRIMARY LOGFILSIZ it is very important to know transactions per minute and now when I want to do that it is so hard to estimate that.. that is also question in Configuration Advisor

Comment: we do not have time to upgrade to fixpack 1..this is production database for sure we will not do it..can you provide me more details to estimate it in GET SNAPSHOT?

Comment: Why are you paying so much attention to the log sizing?  Unless you are running out of log disk space or constantly getting the "Transaction log full" errors you should probably invest your time elsewhere, e.g. installing the latest fix pack.

Comment: Hi, I would not like to get into situation that Transaction log is full because on application which uses this DB is always 200 users logged in. So if that error occur they will not be able to change some field value or insert a new record and similar right? That will happen if I receive the error?

Comment: Clearly, if you are not seeing the error, you have enough log space for your current workload.

Comment: OK so if I understand very well it is not risky operation to change log size. And users will immediately see some kind of error that they can not Save their changes? Because we are not monitoring their system every day